# How can I display 2 mysql queries in a side-by-side table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
column1|status|
12345 | 1
12345 | 1
12345 | 1
12345 | 0
12345 | 0
11111 | 1
11111 | 1
11111 | 0
```

I used this query, but it displays 4 rows and i want them side by side.

```
(SELECT column1, COUNT(*)
 FROM test AS jobstotal
 GROUP BY column1
) UNION
(SELECT column1, COUNT(*)
 FROM test as completedjobs
 WHERE status='1'
 GROUP BY column1
)
```

I did try some inner join, right join, left join and full outer join, but with no success.

the result i want is:

```
column1|totaljobs|column2|completedjobs
12345 | 5 | 12345 | 3
11111 | 3  | 11111 | 2
```

Can you guys tell me what query i should use to get the wanted result?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to get.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: I cannot see how you can derive this result from that data set !?!!?

Comment: Edited my result based on the dataset. primary key is ID, but these 2 are the only 2 columns i am interested in showing. I am trying to do a progress bar for each job (however, each job has multiple rows) in the system, they are identified by a job number (column1) and a status column which is either 0(not completed) or 1 (completed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking to your sample could you are looking for a count based  on case eg:

```
   select column1
      , count(*) as totaljobs
      , sum(status=1) as completedjobs -- or just sum(status)
   from test
   group by column1
```

Comment: scaisEdge, that is exactly what i needed, with 1 small change. status='1' then 1 else 0 end).